# In JavaScript how to set each item into an array from a String started with First braces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with various name started and ended with braces like

```
String a = "[item1,item2,item3,......itemN]"
```

And I want this string as an array-like

```
Array a = ["item1","item2","item3",......"itemN"]
```

So that I can access each data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the array and split the string.

```js
const
    string = "[item1,item2,item3,......itemN]",
    array = string.slice(1, -1).split(',');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on "," and then replace the "[" and  "]" with ""

```js
var a="[item1,item2,item3,itemN]"

var splitted = a.split(",");

splitted[0] = splitted[0].replace("[","");
splitted[splitted.length-1] = splitted[splitted.length-1].replace("]","");

console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: I already used the first answer. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Three liner or two if instead of declaring the const regExp you use it directly into the replace function,

```
let a = "[item1,item2,item3,......itemN]";
const regExp = /[\[\]]/g;
const arr = a.replace(regExp,'').split(',');
console.log('type of arr ' + typeof arr);
console.dir(arr);
```